# Count how many times Class has been changed (Revisions)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, revision

So I am currently doing an analysis of my Spring Java-Project. One thing I want to do, is to count, how many times a file/class has been changed. In Eclipse I can right click a class, select Team --> Show History and it shows me all of the changes.

However counting everything would probably take a while, when I have multiple classes and sometimes more than 100 modifications.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: use the api of your Version control system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **TortoiseSVN** you can see it by clicking right on file and go to TortoiseSVN select **Show Log** on submenu  then in opening windows click **Statics** button . It will show you all changes (monthly, avarage, total file changes)

Comment: I am glad that it helped.